# clear variables in memory

Tags: matlab

I am running the following code:

```
DIRECTORY ='/Users/myfolder/output/cond';
saveF = '/Users/myfolder/output';

Ext = '*cond.mat';
cd(DIRECTORY)
Files = dir(Ext);
process = size(Files,1);
```

However, every time I try to run it, a previous Directory (DIRectory) appears in the workspace, in addition to the variables created in the script. This causes issues later on, because it tries to load files that are in the DIRectory, instead of DIRECTORY.

I tried to call `clear all`, `clear`, and to directly clear from the workspace, but with no success.

I also tried to close Matlab and to restart my computer, but it doesn't work. The previous deleted DIRectory appears again and again in the workspace.

I also thought that the same spelling may have caused the problem. However, even if I change the name DIRECTORY to 'folder', when I run the script, the variable DIRectory reappears....

Comment: Is that really *all* the code you're running?

Comment: Within that script I don't see any possibility to get the variable, but it seems you are processing mat files. Maybe the variable is accidentally stored in one of the mat files and you are loading it again? Run your code in the debugger, having the "Workspace" view opened, and check which line really creates the variable.

Comment: @excaza @Daniel you are both correct. When I open the file that is loaded (`Files = dir(Ext)`) the variable DIRectory is already stored in there. Does it mean that I should save again the file? Or is there a way to delete variables stored in the file? Many thanks.

Comment: Read the documentation for [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html). You can specify an output to load your data into a structure and keep it contained that way or you can load specific variables from the `*.mat` file.